# Flask é só usado por iniciantes?

Tags: python, flask

O Flask só é recomendado para quem não tem experiência em frameworks web, ou seja, para pequenos projectos (projectos académicos) ou é recomendado para desenvolver grandes projectos (projectos da industria)?

Comment: Experiência própria, achei ele bastante compacto e simples, mas com poucos recursos e pouco material escrito sobre como fazer sistemas grandes nele. De qualquer forma, acho válido sim tanto para quem está começando quanto para quem já tem mais experiência.

Comment: Penso que o flask até tem muitos recursos e uma grande comunidade.

Comment: No caso dele a "escalabilidade" vai do conhecimento e de outros frameworks que irão o acompanhar, ele faz a parte importante, cria "rotas" (urls costumizadas e aponta elas pras respostas desejadas), tem suporte a templates, debug, sessão e mais em: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/ - Sim ele faz o que um framework básico web deve fazer e a parte das regras de negocio é muito variante e isto na verdade é algo que esta mais dependente de você desenvolvedor do que do framework e até de tecnologias front-end, mas tudo isto é muito baseado em opiniões...

Comment: As pessoas colocam muito as responsabilidade no framework, sendo que quando na verdade muito da responsabilidade da equipe que desenvolve, como por exemplo coletar as "historias", até o UML (se usar) entre outros padrões de projeto e ao meu ver isto sim irá definir a qualidade real do produto (e claro um "desenvolvedor lider" que realmente conheça a linguagem e as ferramentas).

Comment: Apesar desta pergunta ser classificada como pergunta de opinião, penso que não o seja. Fiz esta pergunta à comunidade porque actualmente utilizo flask a nível profissional e estou super satisfeito, mas continuo a ver o crescimento das frameworks em JS e a utilização do Django por parte da industria. A minha duvida está presente no seguinte aspecto, o porquê do flask ficar de fora da industria? por desconhecimento? ou é mais uma boa tecnologia que ficou de fora por causa da tendência do js?

Answer (score 7):

De forma alguma. O Flask é um framework mais enxuto e com menos opiniões, o que o torna mais fácil de extender (e entender!). Ele é uma boa maneira de se entrar no mundo de desenvolvimento web com Python mas não é apenas um brinquedo.

Muitas vezes você não precisa desenvolver um sistema enorme no servidor porque a maioria da funcionalidade executa no navegador, tipo aplicações de página única (SPA) usando Angular, React, Backbone, etc. Em muitos desses casos tudo que você precisa é um framework que possibilite criar algumas páginas simples e uma API REST para alimentar as chamadas que vêm do JavaScript. Nesses casos eu gosto muito de usar Flask com Flask-RESTful.